# Update_attribute not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment, password-recovery

This is the weirdest thing, but I am building out password reset functionality into my application, and am running into an issue that just doesn't add up. Below is the controller action and class methods that are being called:

Controller action to create a password reset link:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user && !@user.activated_at.nil?
      **@user.create_password_reset_digest**
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "message."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "different message"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

private
  ## Before Filters ##
  def get_user
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  end

  # Confirms a valid user
  def valid_user
    # Unless executes code if conditinal is flase
    unless (@user && !@user.activated_at.nil? && @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

User method that works in dev but not prod

```
def create_password_reset_digest
  self.reset_token = User.new_token
  **update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))**
  **update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)**
end
```

As noted, everything works on dev, when I click on the valid email link in prod, I am redirected to the home screen, I looked at the heroku logs which stated my before_action failed:

```
2016-08-26T19:36:00.208550+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/password_resets/8quvjXgdAKF7fLlWmna0Yg/edit?email=themobio025%40gmail.com" for 98.248.238.131 at 2016-08-26 19:36:00 +0000
2016-08-26T19:36:00.211708+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PasswordResetsController#edit as HTML
2016-08-26T19:36:00.211766+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"email"=>"themobio025@gmail.com", "id"=>"8quvjXgdAKF7fLlWmna0Yg"}
2016-08-26T19:36:00.214843+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "themobio025@gmail.com"]]
2016-08-26T19:36:00.218126+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://qa-themob.herokuapp.com/
2016-08-26T19:36:00.218197+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected
```

Before action:

```
def valid_user
  unless (@user && @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

I then attempted to dig deeper and see what was happening, and I opened up a heroku console session and walked through the reset process. I came to find that when submitting the email for password reset, the link was being generated, but the password reset digest ID was not being saved to the user (via the bolded update attribute above). I have no idea why this isn't being saved to the DB, again it is working totally normally in dev, and my activation email workflow is working totally normally in prod and dev (which uses an almost identical approach).

Comment: In your logs, edit is being called. please post that code.

Comment: @PauloAbreu added

Comment: Replace !@user.activated_at.nil? with @user.active?, much easier to read and less prone to errors. Also you post 2 different versions of valid_user. What is '@user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id])' doing? Valid_user is halting your edit action, so something is wrong. add some logger.info or logger.error to track all the path in production.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a migration which is literally just calling update_attribute on every model object as it goes through the list, and despite taking significant time to run, after it runs, it's like none of the attributes have been updated - and it's only happening in production, not reproducible here at all.

Answer (score 0):

`update_attribute` updates the record only when all validations pass. Check `user.errors`

In order to bypass validation use:

```
user.update_column(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
```